# Scaling a QGrahicsView when MouseWheenTurned first scrolls, then scales

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to add zoom in/out functionality to a graphic I'm drawing in Qt.
What I first did was extend QGraphicsScene with my own class GraphicsScene and overload the wheel event.

```
class GraphicsScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    GraphicsScene(QObject *parent, bool drawAxes){ /*drawing stuff here.. */}
    virtual void wheelEvent(QGraphicsSceneWheelEvent *mouseEvent);   
signals:
    void mouseWheelTurned(int);
};


void GraphicsScene::wheelEvent(QGraphicsSceneWheelEvent* mouseEvent) {
  int numDegrees = mouseEvent->delta() / 8;
  int numSteps = numDegrees / 15; // see QWheelEvent documentation

  emit mouseWheelTurned(numSteps);
}
```

When the wheel is turned, an event is sent to the view which contains the scene, and there a scale is performed:

```
class GraphicsView : public QGraphicsView{
    Q_OBJECT
    qreal m_currentScale;

public:

GraphicsView(QWidget * parent): QGraphicsView(parent){  m_currentScale = 1.0; }
public slots:
    void            onMouseWheelTurned  (int);
};
void GraphicsView::onMouseWheelTurned(int steps) {
    qreal sign = steps>0?1:-1;
    qreal current = sign* pow(0.05, abs(steps));

    if(m_currentScale+current > 0){
        m_currentScale += current;
        QMatrix matrix;
        matrix.scale(m_currentScale, m_currentScale);
        this->setMatrix(matrix);

    }
}
```

This works, but I noticed if I zoom in a lot, for example to the top of the graphic, so that the graphic is no longer fully in the viewport, and then I zoom out, the program first scrolls to the botton of the graphic. I can see the vertical scrollbar sliding down. Only when it has reached bottom, does it start to zoom out. What could be the problem?

I would want to zoom in/ out without this scroll up / down behaviour.

Comment: Rather than handling this in the Scene and sending an event to the View, why not simply handle the event directly in the view with [QGraphicsView::wheelEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#wheelEvent), then simply call its [scale](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#scale) function?

Comment: excellent advice. Thanks.

Comment: that did it! Please answer the original question and I will accept your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off handling this in the Scene and sending an event to the View.

Simply handle the event directly in the view with [QGraphicsView::wheelEvent‌](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#wheelEvent)​, then call its [scale](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#scale) function.